# using jQuery to iterate through an array to create links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to loop through a very simple array in order to create a menu. I have been all around the solution, but have yet to nail it down.

Here's my script:

```
var json_data = [["Womens","/womens"],["Best Sellers","/best-sellers"]];
var json_length = json_data.length;
var inner_length = 0;

for (var i = 0; i<json_length; i++)
{
    inner_length = json_data[i].length;
    for( var j = 0; j<inner_length; j++ ){

        var innerData = json_data[i][j];

        var data = '<a href="' + json_data[j][1] + '">' + json_data[j][0] + '</a><br/>';

        //alert(data);

        $("#content").append(data);

    }
}
```

Basic HTML:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

When I move the code to append to my div within the first for loop (rather than the second), the second object's data is shown twice rather than the first then second. The current code shows both the first and second object's data, but duplicates it due to being inside the second for loop. I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I am at a loss of ideas.

Comment: Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79k32o1j/3/

Comment: That is not JSON, that is a two dimensional array.

Comment: why are you using two loops?

Comment: @Kilmazing you're correct sorry I should have explained better. The JSON will be in the same format once it's ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the array more easily using **[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**:

```
json_data.forEach(function(item) {
  var data = '<a href="' + item[1] + '">' + item[0] + '</a><br/>';
  $("#content").append(data);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z5mrd6zt/)

Comment: Thank you so much @RickHitchcock! This works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle, removed the unnecessary loop:

https://jsfiddle.net/79k32o1j/4/

```
for (var i = 0; i<json_length; i++) {
    var data = '<a href="' + json_data[i][1] + '">' + json_data[i][0] + '</a><br/>';
    $("#content").append(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. This is the exact solution I was looking for! Rick's answer works a bit better for my case, but I wish I could mark both answers correct.